# signed and unsigned in C

Tags: c, casting, int, unsigned, signed

code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    signed x,a;
    unsigned y,b;

    a=(signed)10u;
    b=(unsigned)-10;

    y = (signed)10u + (unsigned)-10;
    x = y;

    printf("a=%d, b=%u",a,b);

    if(x==y)
        printf("\nx=%d, y=%d",x,y);
    else if(x!=y)
        printf("\nx=%u, y=%u",x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
a=10, b=65526
x=0, y=0
```

Please explain this output. I am working on Turbo C.

Comment: How about you ATTEMPT to explain the output?

Comment: i am not able to understand why the value of y is 0 in this case.

Comment: But you haven't posted any attempt or reasoning....break a problem down into steps...

Comment: ok i got this... because the value would be 65536 which is 0 in unsigned. sorry to bother everyone. :\

Comment: A useful advice -- **Don't use tubo C**

Comment: which one do u prefer? gcc?

Comment: Turbo C is ancient, 16-bit and there should be 0 reason to use it. GCC is better than Turbo C in practically every way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

y = 10 + 65526 = 65536 = 0 (mod 16-bits).

You have to remember that at the end of the day, signed or unsigned, it is just bits being assigned to a memory location.  How they are interpreted can be a matter or context.  So writing -10 to an unsigned variable is the same as writing 65526 to it.

Comment: yeah i got that before your comment and i wrote it in the above comments. but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @Himanshu Aggarwal - the least you can do is upvote Jim and mark his answer as "accepted".  IMHO...